# AWS --- ELB configurar content-length headers

Tags: aws, error404

Tengo un problema con mi balanceador de carga (ELB). La página 404 entra desde la IP de la instancia y no desde la URL del balanceador. Desde el balanceador sale un error 502.

Los de AWS me dicen lo siguiente:
In order to resolve this, you have to configure the content-length headers and transfer encoding for 404 at your back end. After which ELB will take it as a complaint and it will throw HTTP 404.

¿Saben qué debo hacer exactamente?

Saludos.

Comment: el balanceador de carga tiene alguna instancia _healthy_??

Comment: Ese comportamiento parece el típico que te encuentras cuando los health checks del balanceador no encuentran ninguna instancia _sana_

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Eferion. La instancia está sana. Todo funciona bien, menos el 404 desde la url del balanceador, como te comenté.

Comment: En AWS me dicen que configure el Content-Length, pero, no sé cómo.

Comment: Por lo que te comentan, debe ser un problema del servidor web

Comment: Sí, eso creo. ¿Tienes idea de cómo hacer esa configuración o de qué se trata?

Comment: He encontrdo este [hilo](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94483) no se si te puede ayudar en algo